# Plugin Development - Is it possible to extend the 'Grid' fieldtype?

Tags: add-on-development, plugin

I'm building a fieldtype plugin that is essentially planned to be an extension of the 'Grid' fieldtype. I can see in the docs how you create a new fieldtype to be used *inside* of a 'Grid' but that's not what I want to do. I'm looking to create a plugin that essentially takes the functionality of a grid but with custom fields already inside.

Is there a way to do this? I'm using EE 3.4.7

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing the same right now.

In short - yes, it's possible. Unfortunately there are almost no docs on that, so I took Grid field as example and tried to re-create it with modified functionality.

For my particular purpose, I sometimes call to functions from grid_lib and grid_parser, and sometimes write my own code (in particular, because my database table is not named following Grid's naming scheme)

I'm also using Grid javascript events, e.g. on('grid:addRow')